# How to get line 'eventType' parameter for sending message

Tags: api, line

Can any one pls let me know how  to get the eventType parameter to send Line messages via api provided for line developer site. The eventType  specified in examples does not work. How to get valid eventType parameter for sending messages.

*Example Post Event API call*

```
POST /v1/events HTTP/1.1

Host: api.line.me

Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

X-LINE-ChannelToken: YOUR_CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
  "to":["u5912407b444e54885d00111f7b0ce375"],

  "toChannel":1383378250,

  **"eventType":"138311608800106203",**

  "content":{

    ...

  }
}
```

**From the docs::**  https://developers.line.me/businessconnect/api-reference#sending_message

I'm try to send using this eventType i  got an error like this

```
{"statusCode":"423","statusMessage":"eventType is invalid."}
```

Comment: We can use same eventType document specified